# Angular 6 problem in HTML retreiving data with asnyc pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to display data from a REST API that needs some time to map the desired request. Therefore I tried the `async` pipe in Angular:

Here is the class:

```
  private json: Observable<JsonResponseDTO>;

  constructor(private dtoService: PoolDTOServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPool();
  }

  getPool() {
    this.json = this.dtoService.getPools();
  }
```

and the template:

```
<div *ngIf="json | async as json; else loading">
  <ng-container *ngIf="json.pools.length >=134; else noItems">
    <div *ngFor="let pool of json.pools">
      {{p.name}}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #noItems>No items</ng-template>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading</ng-template>
```

For a short duration, the loading template shows, but then I get an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: "_co.p is undefined"
```

in the template, line 7:41.
Could someone help me here? Do I use the async pipe correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <div *ngFor="let pool of json.pools">
      {{p.name}}
 </div>
```

Your p is undefined. What you want is:

```
 <div *ngFor="let pool of json.pools">
      {{pool.name}}
 </div>
```

Comment: oh damn, so obvoius... :D

Comment: happens all the time and everyone :-)

Answer (score 0):

the `p.name` will not be found because `p` is not defined anywhere. You should fix that typo and use `pool.name`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="json.pools.length >=134; else noItems">
    <div *ngFor="let pool of json.pools">
      {{pool.name}}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```